# google-github-actions to deploy multiple functions

Tags: firebase, github-actions

I am trying to using official google github actions to deploy multiple functions but so for not get any idea that if it is possible or not using this. Can someone please help me to find out if it possible or not?

Here is the link of github action:
https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions

Comment: Find any useful info yet?